# I am trying to get the average of 1D and 2D arrays. i got the code for both 1D and 2D but its not printing anything for 2D. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, 2d

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AverageNumber {
// Recursively computes average of a[]
static double avgRec(int a[], int i, int n)
{
    // Last element
    if (i == n-1)
        return a[i];
  
    // When index is 0, divide sum computed so far by n.
    if (i == 0)
        return ((a[i] + avgRec(a, i+1, n))/n);
  
    // Compute sum
    return (a[i] + avgRec(a, i+1, n));
}

  
// Function that return average of an array.
static double average(int a[], int n)
{
     return avgRec(a, 0, n);
}
 
// main function
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    int arr[] = {10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int n = arr.length;
  
    System.out.println("The average is " +average(arr, n));
}


static int avgRecursion(int a[][], int i, int j,int f)
{
    
    // Last element
    if (i == f-1)
        return a[i][j];
  
    // When index is 0, divide sum computed so far by n.
    if (i == 0)
        return ((a[i][j] + avgRecursion(a, i+1,j, f))/f);
  
    // Compute sum
    return (a[i][j] + avgRecursion(a, i+1,j, f));
}


    int[][] array;{
    array = new int[3][4];
    

    System.out.println("Enter 12 numbers: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            array[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
   int avg(int a[][], int f)
    int f = array.length;
    int average = avgRecursion(array, 0, f);
    System.out.println("The average of the array: " + average);
}
}
```

I was assigned a task where I should create a question on my own for 1Dimensional, 2Dimensional Arrays and recursion concepts. I chose to get the average of both 1D and 2D arrays. I got the code for both 1D and 2D but its not printing anything for 2D. I am also getting an error where it says " int avg(int a[][], int f)"- it says Syntax error on token "int", record expected andSyntax error, insert "RecordBody" to complete RecordDeclaration. What I am doing wrong? If possible, can you please provide an alternate version/ the correct code?

Comment: You can't define a method (`int avg(int a[][], int f)`) inside an initializer block.

Answer (score 0):

The 2D array logic was never executed. You should either put the scanner logic in main method or in a static block.

```
static int avgRecursion(int a[][], int i, int j,int f)
    {

        // Last element
        if (i == f-1)
            return a[i][j];

        // When index is 0, divide sum computed so far by n.
        if (i == 0)
            return ((a[i][j] + avgRecursion(a, i+1,j, f))/f);

        // Compute sum
        return (a[i][j] + avgRecursion(a, i+1,j, f));
    }
    
    static int[][] array;
    static {
        array = new int[3][4];


        System.out.println("Enter 12 numbers: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                array[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        int f = array.length;
        int average = avgRecursion(array, 0,0, f);
        System.out.println("The average of the array: " + average);
  }
```

There were syntax errors on avgRecursion call-One parameter was missing